# How do you open a file by user input? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file

I want to open a txt file by user input and display it when the code is ran so I can then modify it.

Every time I have tried to open the file it does not open. Do I need to save the file in a certain place or is my code just wrong?

This is what my file looks like if it helps:

[inventory.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9jJd.jpg)

My code:

```
const int max_items = 30;
Item items[max_items];
char mainChoice, subChoice;
int num_items = 0;
int parts;
string filename, description;
ifstream fin;

cout << "Enter the name of the inventory file : ";
getline(cin, filename);

filename = filename.substr(0, filename.length() - 1);

fin.open(filename.c_str());

if (fin.is_open())
{
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin, items[num_items].description); 

        items[num_items].description = items[num_items].description.substr(0, items[num_items].description.length() - 1);

        fin >> items[num_items].num_parts; 
        fin.ignore(100, '\n'); 
        num_items++; 
    }

    fin.close(); 
}

else
{
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your file need to be located under the working directory where is executing your program. Or, you may provide an absolute path (example: `C:\Users\ATSpiro\Desktop\inventory.txt` or `\home\etc\inventory.txt`)

Comment: I saved the file where it should be and I also tried inputting the direct path but it still displays that the file was unable to open.

Comment: why do you use : `filename = filename.substr(0, filename.length() - 1);`
Does "filename " contains the extension ?

Comment: @JaziriRami most likely because the OP thinks there is a trailing `\r` being left behind by `getline()`.  That is a possibility for `getline(fin)`, if the file is using CRLF-style line breaks, but this code is running on a non-Windows platform.  But that is certainly not the case for `getline(cin)`, so that `substr()` should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You are unconditionally removing the last character from `filename` before using it.  `std::getline()` does not output the `'\n'` character that terminates the line.  I'm guessing that you expect an <kbd>Enter</kbd> press on the terminal to generate an `\r\n` sequence and then `std::getline()` to output the `'\r'` and dismiss the `'\n'`.  That is simply not the case when reading from `std::cin`, only `'\n'` is generated, which `std::getline()` does not output.  So you need to get rid of that `substr()` call altogether and just use `filename` as-is:

```cpp
cout << "Enter the name of the inventory file : ";
getline(cin, filename);

//filename = filename.substr(0, filename.length() - 1);

fin.open(filename.c_str());
...
```

However, it is certainly possible for `std::getline()` to output an `'\r'` character when reading from a file, if the file is using CRLF-style line breaks, and the code is not running on Windows.  In that case, you do need to account for the extra `'\r'`, but it should be done conditionally instead, eg:

```cpp
getline(fin, description);

if (!description.empty() && description.back() == '\r')
    description.pop_back();

items[num_items].description = description;
```

---

That being said, there are some other issues with your code:

- [`while (!fin.eof())` is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/).
- when calling a stream's `ignore()` method to discard everything up to a specified delimiter, don't use a hard-coded length value. Use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` instead.
- you are overflowing your `items[]` array, if the file has more than 30 items in it.  You should use a `std::vector` when you don't know the number of items at compile-time.
- you are not parsing the contents of the file correctly at all, given the text file you have shown.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
//#include <vector>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

const int max_items = 30;
Item items[max_items];
int num_items = 0;
//vector<Item> items;

cout << "Enter the name of the inventory file : ";

string filename;
getline(cin, filename);

ifstream fin(filename.c_str());
if (fin.is_open())
{
    // ignore the file header
    fin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    fin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    char description[25];

    while (fin.get(description, 25))
    {
        size_t len = fin.gcount();
        if (len > 0 && description[len-1] == '\r')
            --len;

        /*
        Item item;
        item.description = string(description, len);
        fin >> item.num_parts;
        items.push_back(item); 
        */

        items[num_items].description = string(description, len);
        fin >> item[num_items].num_parts;
        ++num_items;
        if (num_items == max_items)
            break;

        //

        fin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
    }

    fin.close(); 

    // use items as needed...
}
else
{
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, use `std::getline()` to read whole lines from the file, so you don't have to call `ignore()` on each iteration.  You can use `std::istringstream` to parse each line, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
//#include <vector>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

const int max_items = 30;
Item items[max_items];
int num_items = 0;
//vector<Item> items;

cout << "Enter the name of the inventory file : ";

string filename;
getline(cin, filename);

ifstream fin(filename.c_str());
if (fin.is_open())
{
    // ignore the file header
    fin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    fin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    string line;
    while (getline(fin, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        char description[25];

        iss.get(description, 25);

        size_t len = iss.gcount();
        if (len > 0 && description[len-1] == '\r')
            --len;

        /*
        Item item;
        item.description = string(description, len);
        iss >> item.num_parts;
        items.push_back(item); 
        */

        items[num_items].description = string(description, len);
        iss >> item[num_items].num_parts;
        ++num_items;
        if (num_items == max_items)
            break;
    }

    fin.close(); 

    // use items as needed...
}
else
{
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
}
```